# Is there a way to generate documentation for only updated files using Sandcastle Help File Builder tool?

Tags: documentation-generation, sandcastle

I am using Sandcastle help file builder to generate documentation of a project. I added project DLL to the SHFB and it generates documentation for entire project. This process is taking around 10 minutes. I was wondering if it is possible for SHFB to look only for files which have changed in the project and update the documentation based on that so the time to generate entire documentation is not so much on every single run. If there is any plugin available to do that, that could help too.